# How do I paste an url from an image?

Tags: ipad

I want to post an image on a website, but it requires the image's url, which I don't know how to. By the way, I'm on an iPad... could anyone help?

Comment: Is the image on your iPad or an online image?

Comment: it is from photos

Comment: It doesn't have a URL in this case because it's in your local device. You have two options, Either there is an option on the website that enables you to upload a picture instead of using URL, or if there isn't you can upload the image to a storage service like DropBox or GoogleDrive. You can then have a URL for your image.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an app like "[Imgur](https://appsto.re/us/xe9iM.i)"

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imgur-awesome-images-gifs/id639881495?mt=8

Use Upload feature to create and share your own pictures as url.